# Can't Zip RDD with another one while they have equal members - PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have problem in zipping two RDD after filtering the items. This is my code:

```
x = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
x = x.zipWithIndex()

# filtering the first element
m1 = x.filter(lambda z: z[1] > 0)
# filtering the last element
m2 = x.filter(lambda z: z[1] < 3)

#zipping
m1.zip(m2).collect()
# expected output: [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

And this is the error I get:

> ValueError: Can not deserialize PairRDD with different number of items in batches: (1, 2)

while they have equal items!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the wanted output using `1.zipWithIndex` `2.cartesian` `3.filter`:

```
x = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])

#1
x = x.zipWithIndex()

#2
x = x.cartesian(x)

#3
x = x.filter(lambda pair: pair[0][1]+1 == pair[1][1])

print(x.collect())
#output: [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

But still If there is another way to handle this situation, please inform!

Answer (score 1):

You can get your expected output by applying a map function in your zipped rdd

```py
m1.zip(m2).map(lambda x: (x[0][1], x[0][0])).collect()

[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```